# Foreign key constraint fails on one to many

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have 2 tables, Orders and Transaction with one to many mapping from orders to transactions with with foreign key orderId in transaction table.

It is possible that some transactions don't have any order, in which case, orderId is going as 0. There is no order with id 0. This was working until I had to delete the tables and let hibernate regenerate them. Now when I am trying to insert a transaction with order id 0, following exception occurs :

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.fundexpert.dao.Transaction]
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2186)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2666)
        at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:534)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:526)
        at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:241)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:291)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:239)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:319)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:265)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:242)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:479)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:357)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:562)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:550)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:546)
        at com.fundexpert.controller.Store.existingUser(Store.java:408)
        at com.fundexpert.controller.Store.sFactory(Store.java:160)
        at com.fundexpert.servlet.upload.PdfRun.doPost(PdfRun.java:124)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fundexpert`.`transaction`, CONSTRAINT `FK7FA0D2DE80F6DF09` FOREIGN KEY (`orderId`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`))
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1016)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3376)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3308)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1837)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1961)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2543)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1737)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2022)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1940)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1925)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
        ... 59 more
```

Comment: Can you share some code

Answer (score 0):

You can't set orderId to 0. It can be only valid value or null. Probably you do not allow null values in foreign key. You should add to ManyToOne annotation optional=true

```
@ManyToOne(optional = true)
```

Also you have to recreate a table after applying fix, hibernate schema generator can't delete constraints.